# Wordpress doesn't find my custom font

Tags: wordpress, font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfive';
    src: url('wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'chunkfive', 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}
```

The font types are in a folder called 'fonts' in the root file of my theme.

I've added !important just incase Wordpress was overruling it.

According to Chrome devtools, the font-family command is recognised but Open Sans is chosen instead, so there must be a problem linking the fonts file, but I can't figure out what it is.

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks all. The problem was I was using a relative path instead of an absolute one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can assume there's a problem of absolute and relative paths. 
I suggest you to try using the absolute ones, that is to say adding the slash in front of the paths, in order to avoid mismatched URL:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfive';
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/wp-content/themes/onesquad/fonts/chunkfive_ex-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'chunkfive', 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have written this in your theme css file.If so, remove 'wp-content/themes/onesquad/' from your path.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `font.css` file located in your theme's `/css/fonts` folder. Then, if your fonts are in the same `/fonts` folder, you can just enqueue the css file in your `functions.php` file

```
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-fonts', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/fonts.css');
```

In your `fonts.css` file you'd then point to the fonts in the same folder

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfive';
    src: url('chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('chunkfive_ex-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('chunkfive_ex-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This should work just fine.